# Extracting a MetaMask seed phrase over to a private key?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

Currently going over MCD Doc's '[Creating a Value](https://docs.makerdao.com/dai.js/getting-started)' section. 
It requires one to set the Infura api key as well as a private key. Currently, I have a MetaMask account with test ether (Kovan) inside it. Yet, MetaMask only seems to allow you to reveal the private key through a 12-keyword seed phrase. How could I convert this phrase into the proper private key that the MCD docs is looking for (which I assume in this case is just a 64 hexadecimal string)?

Answer (score 2):

Metamask allows to export the private key.

Go to your account, select details. It will show your address and QR code. Below there is a "Export your private key" menu, after typing Metamask password it will reveal the private key.

Comment: Can't upvote this answer but this is the solution for MetaMask